# Testing a React component - determining where the functionality should be tested

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, backbone.js, jasmine, reactjs

I am extremely new to testing in general, not just React testing, so I'm still trying to figure out not only *how* to test, but *what* to test.

Here is my `login` callback that gets called on submit of a form:

```
login() {
    let typedUsername = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.username).value;
    if (!typedUsername) {
        return this.setState({
            errored: true
        });
    }
    // we don't actually send the request from here, but set the username on the AuthModel and call the `login` method below
    AuthModel.set('username', typedUsername);
    AuthModel.login();
},
```

`AuthModel` is a Backbone.js Model. But for this question, lets just say it's an external module that I'm importing into my `Login.jsx` component.

I'm writing a test to see that if a username is typed, then `AuthModel.login()` gets called. Do I want to test that in my `test.Login.js` test file, do I test that in my `test.AuthModel.js` test file?

```
it('calls login when there\'s a username present', () => {
    React.findDOMNode(LoginElement.refs.username).value = 'foo';
    TestUtils.Simulate.submit(form);
    // not sure which direction to take this test
});
```

Current test (in `test.login.js`) for context...

Any advice is appreciated, as like I said, this is genuinely the first testing I've ever done.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want a spy. This will stub out the real implementation of AuthModel and replace it with an object you can make expectations against:

```
spyOn(AuthModel, 'login');
// trigger login somehow
expect(AuthModel.login).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Or if you also want to test the arguments which are passed:

```
expect(AuthModel.login).toHaveBeenCalledWith('username', 's3cretpassw0rd);
```

Comment: Ace, thank you. I _believe_ I ended up with something similar: https://gist.github.com/benhowdle89/3e1cfd863e5e920b79ae My issue was reaching the `AuthModel` from the test, as it was imported into the `Login.jsx` component. Would you say that my approach looks fairly sound as is?